# Should there a be setting where you can disable identification request

Tags: support, tags

I'm new in meta and I'm not sure if this can be possible but looking at the new questions segment, 6 out of 10 posts are identification request. I personally don't want to see spammed identification request everywhere. Maybe in profile page or in the main page between `Favourite Tags` and `Related Tags` there could be `Not Interested Tags` segment which allows users to see everything except those kinds of posts?

Answer (score 7):

If you click Edit on "favourite tags" on the homepage , it also opens an "ignored tags" section.

Feel free to add it to that :)

This fades the questions out, which isn't getting rid of them, but at least they're less visible

Comment: Furthermore, if you click on "set tag preferences", and scroll down to the "Tags" section, you should see an option to switch from "Gray out questions in your ignored tags" to "Hide questions in your ignored tags".